# shorter way to use a counter for a div class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, counter, github-api

im trying to set the 1st div in the list to box2, 2nd and 3rd, to box, and 4th to box3
then repeat boxes 1 through 4.

curious if a shorter way to do it with the counter.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var repos = $('#repositories');
var username = 'username';
var count = 0;
$.getJSON('http://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/show/' + username + '?callback=?',      function(data, status) {
    $.each(data.repositories.reverse(), function() {
        if (this.name != username + '.github.com') {
            count++;
            if (count == 1) {
                var boxes = 'box2';
            } else if (count == 4) {
                var boxes = 'box3';
                count = 0;
            } else {
                var boxes = 'box';
            }
            line = $('<div class="' + boxes + '"> <h3>' + this.name + '</h3> <p>' + this.description + '</p> <p><a href="' + this.url + '">more...</a></p> </div>').hide();
            $(repos).append(line);
            $(line).fadeIn(500);
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: `$(repos).append(line);` it is not necessary to create a jQuery object of another jQuery object. That line can just be: `repos.append(line);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are removing one from the actual value of the `count` variable unless it is equal to zero? If this is the case then you could do this:

```
var boxes = (count === 0) ? 'box' : 'box' + (count - 1);
```

To repeat every four, just reset the `count` variable if it is above four:

```
count++;
if (count > 4) {
    count = 1;
}
```

Here is an edited version of your code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $repos    = $('#repositories'),
        username  = 'username',
        count     = 0;
    $.getJSON('http://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/show/' + username + '?callback=?',      function(data, status) {
        var output = [];
        data.repositories = data.repositories.reverse();
        for (var i = 0, len = data.repositories.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (data.repositories[i].name != username + '.github.com') {
                count++;
                if (count > 4) {
                    count = 1;
                }
                var boxes = (count === 0) ? 'box' : 'box' + (count - 1);
                output[output.length] = '<div class="' + boxes + '"> <h3>' + data.repositories[i].name + '</h3> <p>' + data.repositories[i].description + '</p> <p><a href="' + data.repositories[i].url + '">more...</a></p> </div>';
            }
        }
        var $line = output.join('').hide();
        $repos.append($line);
        $line.fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use lines like this:

```
var boxes = (count == 1) ? 'box2' : (count == 4) ? 'box3' : 'box';
count = (count == 4) ? 0 : count + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you may be looking for is a modulo.

```
count = ( count + 1 ) % 5;
```

Now instead of growing indefinitely, count will be the sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc

Your boxes class seems to be a little odd, with `count = 0`, 'count = 2' and `count = 3` all resulting `"box"`. Assuming that's not an error, I'd probably write that as:

```
classes = ['box', 'box2', 'box', 'box', 'box3'];
boxes = classes[count];
```

That way is a little more readable to me, and makes it simple to rejig the logic as necessary.